# Promise проверка задана ли reject функция

Tags: javascript

```
var f = function(a){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if (a % 2 == 0){
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
  });
};

//1
f(1); //ошибка Uncaught (in promise) undefined

//2
f(1).then(function(){}, function(){}); //ошибки не будет
```

Как избежать появление ошибки "Uncaught (in promise) undefined" в первом случае? Я знаю, что функция не передана. Но, допустим, мне необходим именно такой опциональный сценарий, когда может нужна просто функция, а иногда может требоваться ещё дальнейшие действия при успехе/провале. Проверка на typeof reject даст результат функция в обоих случаях.

Comment: Ещё раз перечитать как работает promise. Ваша вторая `function(){}` не имеет никакого отношения к аргументу `reject` в промизе.

Comment: f(1).then(function(){}, function(){ console.log('сработал reject'); }); //как оно не имеет отношение, если вот такой вызов корректно выведет в консоль указанное сообщение? то есть отработал promise и вызвал reject метод, дальше выполняются какие-то действия внутри него

Comment: @Floyat Вам все верно сказали, перечитайте как работают промисы

Comment: Данная ошибка будет всегда, если нет цепочки с обработчиком для `reject`. Если не нужно чтобы это выводилось - просто добавь обработчик по умолчанию, либо вообще не используй `reject`